# OCR for numbers with gray noisy background

Tags: ocr, noise-cancelling

I tried to run OCR on multiple scanned sheets with numbers like this image (All with same background, digits only):

[image]

But all trials failed!
I tried offline OCRs: gocr, tesseract and couple of online OCRs; but all TOTALLY failed!

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you must tweak those images. I recommend a batch tool like [XnViewMP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) which is free and multiplatform.

It has a file explorer. Select all your images, then go to **Tools** - **Batch convert**. Add actions like I did:

[image: XNViewMP - Batch convert - Actions tab]

Here are my actions:

1. **HLS** - make it grayscale:

   - Hue: 0
   - Lightness: 0
   - **Saturation: -127**
2. **Levels** - lower black level a bit so that the gray noise will disappear

   - Black point: 0
   - **White point:** 212 - may vary depending on image
3. **Reduce noise** filter
4. **Adjust** for increasing the contrast

   - Brightness: 0
   - **Contrast: 127** - this one matters
   - Gamma: 1.06
5. **Minimum** for making the black thicker

   - **Filter size:** 5x5 - may vary depending on image

Don't forget to save as `tiff` (See **Output** tab). After that I run `tesseract`:

```
tesseract test.tif text -psm 7
```

Note I selected PSM mode 7: Treat the image as a single text line. If you have multiple lines you'll probably need to use mode 6 or 3.

And here are the contents of `text.txt` output file:

```
570 394 666 638 043
```

Comment: I wonder if those actions can also be done with [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org).

Answer (score 2):

I tried to recognise your image with [OCR technology by ABBYY](http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/demo):
[image: OCR SDK result]

More information about ABBYY's products you can find at [abbyy.com](http://abbyy.com).
I work for ABBYY and ready to help, if you have questions.

Comment: Is there a digits-only mode? To increase detection rate of scratched images?

Answer (score 0):

```
  import cv2
  import numpy as np
  import pytesseract

  im= cv2.imread('noisyNumbers.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

  cv2.imshow('Gray', im)
  cv2.imwrite('noisyNumbers.jpg', im)

  print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('noisyNumbers.jpg')))
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your answer to explain the code you gave above? thanks!